# HTML dropdown only inputs last row to my SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am a newbie to PHP and trying to create a web-interfaced feedback application. I have created a table in HTML with 5 rows and have scripted it to mysql via PHP file. When I hit submit, the last row entries are added 5 times instead of all rows giving single input each.

HTML form

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<table border="3">
<tr>
<th>Faculty Name</th><th>Subject</th><th>Subject Knowledge</th><th>Teaching 

Meathodlogy</th><th>Punctuality</th><th>Syllabus Coverage</th><th>Responsiveness to Queries</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <select name="staff">
   <option value="staff1">Staff1</option>
   <option value="staff2">Staff2</option>
   <option value="staff3">Staff3</option>
   <option value="staff4">Staff4</option>
   <option value="staff5">Staff5</option>
 </td>
  <td>
  <select name="subject">
   <option value="sub1">Sub1</option>
   <option value="sub2">Sub2</option>
   <option value="sub3">Sub3</option>
   <option value="sub4">Sub4</option>
   <option value="sub5">Sub5</option>
 </td>
 <td>
   <select name="Rate1">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
   <select name="Rate2">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
  </td>
  <td>
   <select name="Rate3">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
  </td>
  <td>
   <select name="Rate4">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
  </td>
  <td>
   <select name="Rate5">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <select name="staff">
   <option value="staff1">Staff1</option>
   <option value="staff2">Staff2</option>
   <option value="staff3">Staff3</option>
   <option value="staff4">Staff4</option>
   <option value="staff5">Staff5</option>
 </td>
 <td>
 <select name="subject">
   <option value="sub1">Sub1</option>
   <option value="sub2">Sub2</option>
   <option value="sub3">Sub3</option>
   <option value="sub4">Sub4</option>
   <option value="sub5">Sub5</option>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate1">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate2">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate3">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate4">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate5">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <select name="staff">
   <option value="staff1">Staff1</option>
   <option value="staff2">Staff2</option>
   <option value="staff3">Staff3</option>
   <option value="staff4">Staff4</option>
   <option value="staff5">Staff5</option>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="subject">
   <option value="sub1">Sub1</option>
   <option value="sub2">Sub2</option>
   <option value="sub3">Sub3</option>
   <option value="sub4">Sub4</option>
   <option value="sub5">Sub5</option>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate1">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate2">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate3">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate4">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate5">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <select name="staff">
   <option value="staff1">Staff1</option>
   <option value="staff2">Staff2</option>
   <option value="staff3">Staff3</option>
   <option value="staff4">Staff4</option>
   <option value="staff5">Staff5</option>
 </td>
 <td>
 <select name="subject">
   <option value="sub1">Sub1</option>
   <option value="sub2">Sub2</option>
   <option value="sub3">Sub3</option>
   <option value="sub4">Sub4</option>
   <option value="sub5">Sub5</option>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate1">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate2">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate3">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate4">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate5">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <select name="staff">
   <option value="staff1">Staff1</option>
   <option value="staff2">Staff2</option>
   <option value="staff3">Staff3</option>
   <option value="staff4">Staff4</option>
   <option value="staff5">Staff5</option>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="subject">
   <option value="sub1">Sub1</option>
   <option value="sub2">Sub2</option>
   <option value="sub3">Sub3</option>
   <option value="sub4">Sub4</option>
   <option value="sub5">Sub5</option>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate1">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate2">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate3">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate4">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="Rate5">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit id="submit"> <input type="reset" value="reset">
```

insert.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("feedback", $con); 

if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) { 
if($_REQUEST['Staff']== ""){ 
    $_REQUEST['Staff'] = NULL; 
  }
 }

$sql="INSERT INTO feedback(Staff, subject, Rate1, Rate2, Rate3, Rate4, Rate5)
VALUES
('$_POST[staff]','$_POST[subject]','$_POST[Rate1]','$_POST[Rate2]','$_POST[Rate3]','$_POST[Rate4]','$_POST[Rate5]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }



mysql_select_db("feedback", $con); 

if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) { 
if($_REQUEST['Staff']== ""){ 
    $_REQUEST['Staff'] = NULL; 
  }
 }

$sql="INSERT INTO feedback(Staff, subject, Rate1, Rate2, Rate3, Rate4, Rate5)
VALUES
('$_POST[staff]','$_POST[subject]','$_POST[Rate1]','$_POST[Rate2]','$_POST[Rate3]','$_POST[Rate4]','$_POST[Rate5]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }


mysql_select_db("feedback", $con); 

if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) { 
if($_REQUEST['Staff']== ""){ 
    $_REQUEST['Staff'] = NULL; 
  }
 }

$sql="INSERT INTO feedback(Staff, subject, Rate1, Rate2, Rate3, Rate4, Rate5)
VALUES
('$_POST[staff]','$_POST[subject]','$_POST[Rate1]','$_POST[Rate2]','$_POST[Rate3]','$_POST[Rate4]','$_POST[Rate5]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }


mysql_select_db("feedback", $con); 

if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) { 
if($_REQUEST['Staff']== ""){ 
    $_REQUEST['Staff'] = NULL; 
  }
 }

$sql="INSERT INTO feedback(Staff, subject, Rate1, Rate2, Rate3, Rate4, Rate5)
VALUES
('$_POST[staff]','$_POST[subject]','$_POST[Rate1]','$_POST[Rate2]','$_POST[Rate3]','$_POST[Rate4]','$_POST[Rate5]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }


mysql_select_db("feedback", $con); 

if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) { 
if($_REQUEST['Staff']== ""){ 
    $_REQUEST['Staff'] = NULL; 
  }
 }

$sql="INSERT INTO feedback(Staff, subject, Rate1, Rate2, Rate3, Rate4, Rate5)
VALUES
('$_POST[staff]','$_POST[subject]','$_POST[Rate1]','$_POST[Rate2]','$_POST[Rate3]','$_POST[Rate4]','$_POST[Rate5]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo $values;

mysql_close($con);
?>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=thankyou.html" />
</body>
</html>
```

I know my PHP code is a little silly but I have coded it learning it from online tutorials. I have included an auto-increment 'ID'  column in the database but not set it as primary key. Any suggestions or solutions would be of great help.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and note that a PHP null, the way you're using it, will simply be converted to an empty string once you've built your `$sql`. Your insert query will be executed every page load as well, even if no form was submitted

Comment: Why you are using each elements repeatedly (5times) ?

Comment: Sidenote: You have more than one element name `<select name="Rate1">` `<select name="Rate2">`  `<select name="Rate3">` etc. etc. etc. so don't ask yourself why.

Comment: But the BIG problem is this `name="submit id="submit"` - missing quote around `name="submit` plus, your `if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit']))` is looking for a button name `Submit` while yours is called `submit`, lowercase `s`. So, `S != s` and vice-versa.

Comment: Plus, `Staff != staff` most or all of your form elements' names need to match letter for letter, case for case.

Comment: all the responses are a little overwhelming.. I did assign individual element names for each row, my problem is sorted now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same name for all the select tag. Each name must be unique.

**EDIT**

As everyone has pointed out, you are prone to sql inyection attacks. Also sorry that my original answer was too short.

Focusing in the answer of the original question. You have the same value 5 times because you have the same name on all your select so php get the same value 5 times.

Comment: I don't know why this was voted down; makes sense. As short an answer as it is, it does cover some of the issues with the OP's code.

Comment: Read my comments also under OP's question. There are many errors with it.